# error when trying to run jupyter notebook: ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command

Tags: drivers, 18.04, anaconda

I haven't used this computer in about three months, so when I turn it on and want to run jupyter notebook, I get this error:

```
john@john-Satellite-L55Dt-B:~$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/bin/jupyter", line 7, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.command import main
ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command
```

I looked at my bashrc profile and the path

export PATH="/home/john/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

is still in the profile. So I'm not sure what broke or how to fix it. Unless I have to re-install anaconda3, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Can you run any conda commands e.g. `conda search jupyter`? That might be a good start to see if you conda environment is completely broken. You could possibly try reinstalling jupyter. See: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

Comment: @KevinBowen apparently I cannot, I get this error here:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ImportError: No module named conda.cli

Comment: Have you tried to cd into the directory where the binary is located and try to run directly from there to see if it is a more complicated path issue? Other than that, yeah, if you can't list your conda envs/packages or create a new conda env, I don't think you have much choice but to re-install...

Comment: @KevinBowen yes sir, I did that.